# Windows-to-Linux: Data completely erased!

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, windows-xp

I'm a student on a high school of Tenerife,Los Silos. The computer I use on technology had windows XP, and I made a class work on that OS. Today, I came class and I found my computer without Windows! Someone installed Ubuntu and erased all the data. I can't found my class work and it was very important: it was hard to do and I have to present it this wednesday. Can you tell me if I can recover my data from Windows? I'll be very thankful if you answer me :)

Comment: I feel your pain. But I don't think we can do much.
Are you sure that ubuntu replaced xp? or is it just not showing xp in boot menu?

Comment: If the person who installed Ubuntu did not format your data partitions you may still see your files after choosing this partition in the file browser. Else you will need data recovery tools: https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu - use testdisk to search for and recover your class work files.

Comment: We need more information. The most likely thing is that Windows is still there and you just need to reboot your machine. If not, you need to speak to the person in charge of your school's computers. It is very likely your data are still there but it is hard for us to help without more information about the system. Can you log on to Ubuntu?

Comment: @SirajusSalekin: a default Ubuntu installation does not overwrite exisiting partitions it only creates a new partition table and quick-formats the drive. Most of preexisting data are untouched and can easily be recovered with the appropriate tools.

Comment: @Takkat, I'm aware of that. Depends on how the setup was done. That's why I asked.